# ReDim Preserve 2D out of range

Tags: vba, excel

this function gets two parameters a range and one value to match inside range then return an array with matched values and their address. but it gives an error with `ReDim Preserve` and also it gives error when the array is empty (not matched any value)

```
Function filter_range_value(rng As String, selected_value As String) As Variant 
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim array_storage() As Variant
    Dim element As Integer

    element = 1

    For Each cell In Range(rng)
        If InStr(cell, selected_value) > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve array_storage(element, 1)
            array_storage(element, 0) = cell
            array_storage(element, 1) = cell.address
            element = element + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    filter_range_value = array_storage
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try `Redim Preserve array_storage(0 to element, 0 to 1)` ?

Comment: You can only redim preserve the last dimension.  In a 2D it is the second, 3d the third, ....

Answer (score 4):

To fix your problem:

You cannot change the first dimension in a 2D array with Redim Preserve.

Use COUNTIF() to find the correct number of rows needed.

```
element = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "*" & selected_value & "*")
ReDim array_storage(1 To element, 1 To 2)
```

---

Other notes:

I also changed the `rng` to a `Range` and not a `String` so we do not need to force vba to do the parsing.

```
=filter_range_value(A:A,"a")
```

The line `Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)` just ensures we are not doing any uneeded iterations.  This will allow a full column reference for `rng` and it will only iterate those that are in the usedrange.

Currently you have it looking for case specific strings.  If you want to make it not case specific use:

```
    If InStr(1, cell, selected_value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

The defualt is `vbBinaryCompare` which is case specific.

---

```
Function filter_range_value(rng As Range, selected_value As String) As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim array_storage() As Variant
Dim element As Long
Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)
element = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "*" & selected_value & "*")
ReDim array_storage(1 To element, 1 To 2)
element = 1
For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(1, cell, selected_value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        array_storage(element, 1) = cell
        array_storage(element, 2) = cell.Address
        element = element + 1
    End If
Next cell
filter_range_value = array_storage
End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend

Comment: @HaithamDarweesh if this answered your question, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you use a `VBA.Collection` or `Scripting.Dictionary`? This would be much easier to work with than an array and you need not concern yourself with allocating correct size at runtime. The key of collection/dictionary can be the range address.

Comment: This is a good suggestion but you should include a code example